# Android react-native changing upgrading com.android.tools.build:gradle results in invalid APKs

Tags: android, react-native

If I change from `classpath ‘com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'` to `classpath ‘com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'` and nothing else, the Android builds create invalid APKs which are rejected by the emulators. Does anybody know why? I have tried doing so many things, including upgrading all the way to 7.1.2 (cannot work because of broken packages). I need to upgrade past 3.5.4 for a react-native upgrade. Thanks.

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK
```

The most notable error from the logcat is: `com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: Package /data/app/AppName/base.apk code is missing`

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
```

with

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'
```

and then it finally created a valid APK.